# Dialog box not displayed on clicking a button selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a button 'Add' in my web app that opens a new window(frame to be precise). The new frame has a button 'Browse' which on clicking opens a 'File Upload' dialog box. The opening of the 'File Upload' is not happening in selenium. The page is designed in such a way that a text box is placed before the 'Browse' button. The dialog box opens either on clicking the blank space of the text box or the 'Browse' button. I tried the simulation of click in selenium in both the text box and the 'Browse' button. But nothing happens. Selenium doesn't even report any error. Below is the dom of the element in question here:

`<span class="ruFileWrap ruStyled">
<input id="ctl00_Popup_Content_ctrlUploadfile0" class="ruFileInput" type="file" name="ctl00_Popup_Content_ctrlUploadfile0" size="73" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -5000px;">
<input class="ruFakeInput" type="text" size="72">
<input class="ruButton ruBrowse" type="button" value="Browse">
</span>`

The python code I tried:

**1. doesn't work**

```
driver.switch_to_frame('dlgUpload') #To switch control from main window to the current frame
btnBrowse = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_Popup_Content_ctrlUploadfile0')
btnBrowse.click()
```

**2. doesn't work**

```
btnBrowse = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('html#popup body.popup div.popup_content_wrapper center form#aspnetForm.form div div#ctl00_Popup_Content_pnlFiles div.ContentPane div#ctl00_Popup_Content_ctrlUpload.RadUpload.RadUpload_Default ul#ctl00_Popup_Content_ctrlUploadListContainer.ruInputs li span.ruFileWrap.ruStyled input.ruButton.ruBrowse')
btnBrowse.click()
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What is 'dlgUpload' in your first attempt code? In Java implementation, frame accepts either integer or "windows handler" which is a string? In your case 'dlgUpload' is string windows handler?

Comment: have you tried using the `selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains` class for this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688430/nosuchelementexception-when-trying-to-use-selenium-python/24704262#24704262

Comment: The ActionChains() method too isn't making things work –  ChandiranV 2 mins ago - removed answer as it didn't solve this particular issue.

Comment: @Uday i think you mean "id" or "name". not "windows handler" `:)`

Comment: @OP make sure of three things.  1) that when you specified `dlgUpload`, that it was a frame / iframe's name, or ID.  2)  that the `ct100_Popup_Content_ctrlUploadFile0` isn't dynamic. If that 0 is changing, then you need to use a better CSS selector. Something like: `[id*='ctrlUploadfile']`. 3) Make sure your casing is correct

Comment: @sircapsalot, if any of your 3 suggestions is wrong in my case, then wouldn't selenium had thrown error message saying WebElement not found? Just saying

Comment: well you don't specify an actual error, only "nothing happens" so it could be a number of things, just trying to narrow it down `:)`