# Selenium, Trying to Find an Element [Python]

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying type the username and password into my University mail using `Selenium` module. This is the id's attribute value that I'm trying to locate:

`<input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_UsernameTextBox" name="username" tabindex="1" placeholder="FAU Net ID" value="" autocomplete="false" type="text">`

Here's how I'm trying to find it in my program:

`userElem = browser.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_UsernameTextBox')`

But this is the error that I'm running into:

Exception -:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_UsernameTextBox')
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 269, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="ContentPlaceHolder1_UsernameTextBox"]
```

Thanks and any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

for reference this is the page

[Link](https://sso.fau.edu/login?SAMLRequest=fVLJTsMwEL0j8Q%2BW79kqschqUhUQohJL1AYO3Fxnklj1Ejx2C39PmoKAA70%2Bv3nLeKazd63IFhxKa3KaxSklYIStpWlz%2BlzdRpd0VpyeTJFr1bN58J1ZwlsA9GSYNMjGh5wGZ5jlKJEZrgGZF2w1f7hnkzhlvbPeCqsoWdzkdN1s%2BrXs%2BqbTDYDaqLo1slWbttMCTG%2Bhbmut7IaSl%2B9Yk32sBWKAhUHPjR%2BgNDuPsjSaXFRpytKMnWWvlJRfTlfSHBoci7U%2BkJDdVVUZlU%2BrahTYyhrc48DOaWttqyAWVu%2FtS44otwPccIVAyRwRnB8CXluDQYNbgdtKAc%2FL%2B5x23vfIkmS328U%2FMglPGh5iqEPCBdJiXCsbm7lf%2Bzyem3%2F70uJHeZr8kiq%2BvmvfYnFTWiXFB5krZXfXDrgfKngXhga31mnu%2F3fL4mxEZB01I5UFgz0I2UioKUmKg%2Bvfuxiu5RM%3D&RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fa%2Ffau.edu%2FServiceLogin%3Fservice%3Dmail%26passive%3Dtrue%26rm%3Dfalse%26continue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmail.google.com%252Fmail%252F%26ss%3D1%26ltmpl%3Ddefault%26ltmplcache%3D2%26emr%3D1%26osid%3D1)

Comment: It hard to tell without looking at the page. You can make sure that element is present on the page using DevTools, Firebug etc

Comment: Doesn't Selenium have a `find_element_by_name()` function too? You could try that one also, if not use `xpath`

Answer (score 2):

If Selenium is telling you it couldn't find the element, then it isn't there.  There are typically a few possible reasons for this:

1. You did something silly like mistyping the element name.  Are you *sure* that's the correct element ID?
2. You aren't on the page you thought you were.  Are you *sure* you're on the right page?  Have you looked at `browser.page_source` to double-check?
3. The element isn't there when the page loads, but is added to the page later via Javascript, perhaps after a set time delay or when some event happens such as a mouse click.  Does the page have javascript like this?

Comment: Another possibility is that the element is in a different frame ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24688430/190597), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32636613/190597)), in which case the solution is to call `driver.switch_to.frame`.

Comment: Ooo, I always forget about frames!

Comment: You know I did `brower.page_source` and couldn't locate any of the elements, that was the problem. I'm putting this new window's url with into `browser.get(url)' and it's now fixed. Thanks a lot.